# Word counter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie in angular so please bear with me. I have a character counter and word counter in my textarea. My problem is that everytime I press the space, it is also being counted by getWordCounter function. How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="notesContent" type="text" class="form-control" rows="10" ng-model="notesNode.text" ng-trim="false" maxlength="5000"></textarea>

<span class="wordCount">{{getWordCounter()}}</span>
<span style="float:right">{{getCharCounter()}} / 5000</span>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getCharCounter = function() {
   return  5000 - notesNode.text.length;
}

$scope.getWordCounter = function() {
   return $.trim(notesNode.text.split(' ').length);
}
```

Comment: What triggers getWordCounter? Your textarea only has a model set, no listener for changes in it as far as i can see

Comment: I already edited my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like  you need to call 'trim' before calling split, like this:

```
$scope.getWordCounter = function() {
    return notesNode.text.trim().split(' ').length;
}
```

If you want to support multiple spaces between words, use a regular expression instead:

```
$scope.getWordCounter = function() {
    return notesNode.text.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
}
```

### Filter implementation

You can also implement `wordCounter` as a filter, to make it reusable among different views:

```
myApp.filter('wordCounter', function () {
    return function (value) {
        if (value && (typeof value === 'string')) {
            return value.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    };
});
```

Then, in the view, use it like this:

```
<span class="wordCount">{{notesNode.text|wordCounter}</span>
```

See [Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJvB4/)

Comment: It's actually working but still incomplete. Everytime I insert another word and then have a few spaces in between them, it is also being counted by the getWordCounter  function.

Comment: See the edited answer, it uses a regular expression to split words by multiple spaces as well...

Comment: Does trim has any value here? I guess it would work correctly without trim.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more advanced answer for your problem, since it can be reusable as a directive:

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);

App.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope){
  var notesNode = {
    text: '',
    counter: 0
  };

  this.notesNode = notesNode;
}]);

App.directive('counter', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      counter: '='
    },
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, model) {
      if (!model) { return; }
      model.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
        var count = model.$viewValue.split(/\b/g).filter(function(i){
          return !/^\s+$/.test(i);
        }).length;

        scope.counter = count;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

And the HTML

```html
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="Main as main"></div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="main.notesNode.text" class="county" counter="main.notesNode.counter">
  <span ng-bind="main.notesNode.counter"></span>
</body>
```

See it in here http://plnkr.co/edit/9blLIiaMg0V3nbOG7SKo?p=preview

It creates a two way data binding to where the count should go, and update it automatically for you. No need for extra shovelling inside your scope and controllers code, plus you can reuse it in any other input.

Comment: How about a filter? I think it will result in a shorter / more readable code than using a directive for this task...

Comment: well, he could use a filter, but would require more code to achieve the same result. directives are the way to go for these kind of tasks, stuffing things like this in your controllers scope isn't good practice